# How to find the maximum average interval that contains the given interval?

Tags: algorithms

Specifically, given a sequence $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ and two numbers $i,j(i\le j)$ , find two numbers $a,b(a\le i\le j\le b)$, such that $\frac{\sum\limits_{k=a}^{b}{{{x}_{k}}}}{b-a+1}$ is maximum.
It is clear that we can design a simple algorithm that the time complexity is $O({{n}^{2}})$. I want to design an algorithm which the time algorithm is less than $O({{n}^{2}})$ such that $O(n\log (n))$ or $O(n)$.
But I find it's not easy to design it. I try to design a greedy algorithm, but unfortunately they are all wrong. There are four typical counter examples. The first one is $\begin{matrix}100 & 1 & 0 & 10 & 1000\\\end{matrix}$, $i=j=3$. The best solution is $a=3,b=5$. The second one is $\begin{matrix}2 & 10 & -10 & 10 & 2  \\\end{matrix}$, $i=j=3$. The best solution is $a=2,b=4$. The third one is $\begin{matrix}9 & 10 & 0 & 10 & 9  \\\end{matrix}$, $i=j=3$. The best solution is $a=1,b=5$. The fourth one is $\begin{matrix}4 & 6 & 10 & -10 & 10 & 6 & 4 \\\end{matrix}$, $i=j=4$. The best solution is $a=2,b=6$.
I try to solve this problem by recursive, but they all can't reduce the time complexity.

Comment: You may be interested in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0311020) regarding a related problem. Your problem is similar to the uniform case where $w_{\rm min} = j-i+1 \ge 1$, $w_{\rm max} = n$, and $w_k = 1$ for $1 \le k \le n$. You'll need to eliminate results where the segment $S(a,b)$ doesn't contain your desired $S(i,j)$.

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128221/how-to-quickly-find-the-maximum-average-interval

Comment: Thanks. I found the algorithm can use in this problem just need a little change.